# Could you please explain the 'font' for me thoroughly?

Tags: fonts

Before I don't care about the font, I knew little about a variety of fonts.
Recently I encountered an issue related to font, thus I searched a couple of articles about font.

I have some doubts.

1. What does **san-serif, san, serif** stand for? Are they specific font or only standards?
2. What does **Helvetica, Arial** stand for? Are they specific font?

What's the relationship between **san-serif, san, serif,Helvetica, Arial** ,I am pretty confused.

Following is my test.

I am using **jasperreport** to generate PDF report, If I configure my pdf font using **Helvetica**, following is the result when I execute the command **fc-list** on Linux OS.

```
[clodev@localhost pdf]$  fc-list
Bitstream Vera Sans Mono:style=Bold
Bitstream Vera Sans:style=Oblique
Bitstream Vera Sans:style=Roman
Bitstream Vera Sans Mono:style=Oblique
Bitstream Vera Sans:style=Bold
Bitstream Vera Serif:style=Roman
Bitstream Vera Sans Mono:style=Bold Oblique
Bitstream Vera Sans:style=Bold Oblique
Bitstream Vera Sans Mono:style=Roman
Bitstream Vera Serif:style=Bold
```

Can PDF report be generated successfully? I can't find the font **Helvetica** in the above result. But My test result is OK, however the production environment reported an error about the font not be found.

Answer (score 0):

Serif and Sans-serif both refers to two distinct categories of Typefaces.
Among **Serifs** there are for example Times New Roman and Georgia fonts.

**Sans-serifs** are the one with '[less projecting features](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sans-serif)', among them there are fonts such as Arial or Helvetica

Don't know much about Jasper Reports, but usually you can refer to a particular category, instead of a specific font, and the renderer will adapt its font choice depending on the available fonts, or you can specify a particular font to be rendered, in that case the font file has to be installed in your environment.

Comment: Why does my Linux OS only have **Sans** or **Serif** and not have particular font according to the result of the command **fc-list** above?

Answer (score 0):

**"Serifs"** are details in a font at the end of each stroke. For example, take a look at "Times New Roman": At the end of each stroke, there is a little horizontal line. This supports the reader in printed text but can problematic for on-screen reading because of the low resolution of screens. High-resolution screens ("Retina" if you use Apple) might change that.

**Sans Serif** means "Without serifs" (sans is the french word for "without").

Helvetica and Arial (and Bitstream Vera) are different "typefaces" (fonts). All three are "sans serif", all three look very similar.

You should definitely read "The Non-Designer's Design Book" by Robin Williams, even if you are only casually interested in this topic.

I don't know about Jasper Reports, but probably "Bitstream Vera" has been chosen because it is very similar to Helvetica and comes with a very liberal license.

Further reading:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helvetica
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitstream_Vera
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serif
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sans-serif

Comment: Bitstream Vera doesn’t look like Helvetica at all to me. More like Verdana.